# ImportError: No module named rospkg

Tags: ros, rospkg, pythonpath

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run fake_turtlebot.launch.  I keep getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py", line 60, in <module>
    import xacro
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from roslaunch import substitution_args
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    import rospkg
ImportError: No module named rospkg
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py '/home/brent/catkin_ws/src/rbx1/rbx1_description/urdf/turtlebot.urdf.xacro'] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="$(arg urdf_file)" name="robot_description"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
brent@brent-Dell-DM051:~$
```

I thing that my pythonpath is set wrong, but I am not sure how to fix it.
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250711/importerror:--no-module-named-rospkg/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2016-12-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> ImportError: No module named rospkg
> ```
>
> I thing that my pythonpath is set wrong, but I am not sure how to fix it.

A bit too little info is provided so I can only assume that you don't have `python-rospkg` installed. It's a non-ROS, standalone pkg that gets installed under `/usr/lib` instead of under `/opt` as other ROS packages, which means Python can find it without extra `PYTHONPATH` (maybe a [good read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850908/what-exactly-should-be-set-in-pythonpath)).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2018-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0